# Constant voltage intercom / PA: 25v and 70v on speaker cable?

Tags: audio, constant-voltage, distributed

I am tasked with hooking up some old analog constant voltage intercom and public address speakers to a new digital / networked intercom system. This is currently all shut down and not being used.

Whoever did this used regular speaker audio cable to carry both 25 volt and 70 volt, with 70 volts on the bare "shield" wire that is wrapped around the red and black wires.

[image: amplifier terminals - common: black, 25 volt: red, 70 volt: bare]

.

In this next image, a phone cabling "Type 66" punchdown 2-terminal block is used for the red and black wires, while the busbar next to it carries the 70v terminal for all the audio cable shields.

[image: distribution bus wiring]

Is this a shock hazard? I suppose it might acceptable if the constant voltage transformer wiring is entirely isolated from chassis ground. But I also don't think the shield is supposed to be used this way?

It looks like this needs to be ripped out and redone, with the 70v removed from the speaker cable shield. Just pick one or the other voltage for the red/black wires at the speaker, with the shield grounded to the amplifier case.